# Callback after "cancel entire order" in google web based in-app-payments

Tags: google-checkout, android-pay

We're using Google In-App Payments for Web Apps

Everything works fine for payment.

But we are trying to automate the refund process.

We use "cancel entire order" in checkout.google.com/seller order page

But we seem to receive no callback for the refund notification.

I'm testing this in the sandbox.  Should it work there?  Does it work in production?

Thanks,
Ralph

Answer (score 1):

The Google In-App Payments API for Web Apps has no callbacks for refunds. 
You get a callback only for a new order or a subscription cancellation.

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback

Comment: Thanks Mihai, is there any plan to have callback for refund?  I believe that the google checkout callback had support for this and PayPal does.